# Access to host mongodb from docker windows container

Tags: mongodb, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a Visual Studio project with docker support added. It has docker compose file with network section (I use Windows Containers):

```
services:
  auth:
    environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
    - "80"
  networks:
    default:
      external:
        name: nat
```

Docker nat network has

```
"Subnet": "172.17.224.0/20",
"Gateway": "172.17.224.1"
```

So I can access aspnet core 2 app from host via http://172.17.228.37/api/account/test

Exec ipconfig on docker image returns:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.228.37
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.224.1
```

The app uses Mongo. MongoDB server runs on the host (not inside docker) and bind to 0.0.0.0 in the mongod.cfg

```
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
```

So inside the docker i use connection string as mongodb://172.17.224.1:27017 and the application CANNOT connect to host mongodb. However the gateway IP (172.17.224.1) ping is OK. Am I missing something from configuring mongodb, docker or the net core 2 app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to expose ports in container or attach container port to host port

Comment: @trigun117 exposing ports is for accessing container from host and I want to access host from container

Comment: @lavrik did you ever get this sorted? I have a similar problem

Comment: @MarkRobson Yeah as of version 18.03 you can use reserved DNS name host.docker.internal